# What' wrong with this article? It failed in compilation via XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, errors, miktex

I wrote an article as follows.

```
      \documentclass{article}
      \usepackage{fontspec}
      \usepackage{unicode-math}
      \setmathfont{Asana Math}
      \setmainfont{Bitstream Vera Serif}
      \begin{document}

      \begin{equation}
              \max\sum_{(i,j)\in A}c_{ij}x_{ij}
      \end{equation}
      \end{document}
```

Unfortunately it failed to make a pdf by XeLaTeX...

```
      Package scrlfile, 2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
              Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

      ) (d:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math-table.tex))Running          
       miktex-makemf.exe...
      miktex-makemf: The ICU source file could not be found.

      Running hbf2gf.exe...


      hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)



      Couldn't find `I.cfg'

      miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font ICU.

      ! Font \zf@basefont="Asana Math/ICU" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file
      or installed font not found.
      <to be read again>
               \scan_stop:
      l.5 \setmathfont{Asana Math}

      ?
```

I'm sure that I did install these packages. So it troubled me.

Comment: The error says it can't find Asana Math, do you have that font installed?

Comment: Xetex doesn't find asana math. So either it isn't there, not at the correct place or some cache is not up-to-date. Run `fc-cache -f`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can see it in MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It returns that "FC: Cannot open -cache..."

Comment: Did you add a space after `fc`? There isn't one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, "fc -cache -f".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I typed it again without the space. It returned that Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file "C:\CTEX\UserData/fontconfig/config/localfonts.conf"
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I know the problem: My CTEX is in driver D. So how to let it to know?

Comment: Your *main* miktex tree is in D. But miktex creates also trees in other drives. My main tree in in J, while the UserConfig tree is in C (and has in `fontconfig/config` a localfonts.conf). Check the pathes of your roots in miktex settings. Is `C:\CTEX\UserData` the tree named `UserConfig`?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite familiar with that. What is main tree?

Comment: @Popopo In your MWE nothing KOMA-Script related is loaded, but the log excerpt does show this! Is this perhaps from an former version? If yes, show a log file from compliation of the MWE you’ve given. Then again: Check the user permissions.

Comment: @Speravir Well, I have found where the problem is: I installed a new version basically which do not concluded some packages I needed to use, despite they were indeed installed in the old version. Thus I had to reinstall them in manager.